# CLLocationManager didUpdateLocations not being called iOS 8 with plist entries

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I'm having some issues with CLLocationManager. This code used to work on iOS 8.2 but since upgrading to 8.3 it doesn't work. Here is the code for setting up the location manager which is called on startup.

```
let distanceThreshold:CLLocationDistance = 100.0

var currentLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D?

override init() {
    assert(locMan == nil)
    super.init()
    locMan = self

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    currentLocation = manager.location.coordinate

    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == .Background {
        PlacesManager.fetchNearbyPlaces(LocationManager.getLocationManager().currentLocation!, radius: distanceThreshold, callback: placesCallback)
    }
}
```

With this code didUpdateLocations is never called despite it being called before.
I have added the relevant entries to the Info.plist file:
[image: Info.plist screenshot]

I have tried it on both a device and the simulator and neither works. In fact it seems that it is no longer requesting location authorisation anymore if I delete the app and reinstall.

I know I'm missing something stupid but I can't workout what the hell it is.

I'd appreciate any help people can provide.

Cheers,
Gerard

Comment: Shouldn't `locationManager` be an instance variable instead of a local variable in `init`?

Comment: Yeh I noticed a lot of people doing that but never actually using the instance variable. Each of the location manager callbacks provide the manager so not really any need to keep a reference to it unless you want to stop it or play around with it outside of a callback.

Comment: The [CLLocationManager documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html) says: "To configure and use a CLLocationManager object to deliver events...Create an instance of the CLLocationManager class and store a strong reference to it somewhere in your app.  Keeping a strong reference to the location manager object is required until all tasks involving that object are complete.  Because most location manager tasks run asynchronously, storing your location manager in a local variable is insufficient."

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you, I don't really understand why that is required but thats fixed it. Must be garbage collected I guess? Make it an answer and I'll give you credit. Thanks Anna.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer from Anna:

The CLLocationManager documentation says: "To configure and use a CLLocationManager object to deliver events...Create an instance of the CLLocationManager class and store a strong reference to it somewhere in your app. Keeping a strong reference to the location manager object is required until all tasks involving that object are complete. Because most location manager tasks run asynchronously, storing your location manager in a local variable is insufficient."

Comment: All references are strong references by default unless otherwise specified in Swift.

Comment: They don't mean a strong reference in this case. They mean a reference that does not go out of scope while still being used. In my situation it wen't out of scope after init.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer, if you are using the simulator. You have to select a location **after** the app is running (Debug->Location->apple for apple headquarters). I set the location and assumed that the next time I ran the app that `didUpdateLocations` would be called with what I had set previously, but that assumption was wrong.